# Backbone.Router route change event trigger twice

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

This is my Coffescript Router class:

```
class App.Router extends Backbone.Router

  initialize: ->

    console.log 'Router.init'

    @on 'all', ->
      console.info 'route changed'

  routes:
    '': 'home'
    'test': 'test'

  home: ->
    console.log 'home routed'

  test: ->
    console.log 'test routed'
```

the "@on 'all'" callback seems to trigger twice (double console.info on my firebug...) when i reload my localhost page...

this is my firebug output:

```
App.init
Session.init
Router.init
home routed
route changed
route changed
```

As you can see the "route changed" output is placed after my home route...

And finally this is my bootstrap code (with my App namespace...), where i placed the history.start

```
App =
  init: ->
    console.log 'App.init'
    @session = new App.Model.Session
    @router = new App.Router
    # @userPanel = new App.View.UserPanel
    Backbone.history.start pushState: true

  Model: {}
  View: {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `all` event is a special event listener syntax which captures **all** events of any type triggered by the source object. I'm guessing the other event is actually not a `route` event at all, but a `route:name` event.

To catch all routes, just use the `route` event instead:

```
@on 'route', ->
  console.info 'route changed'
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Problem solved, i still have problem to think in the javascript event way T_T. By the way, why the home route is triggered before my onRoute callback?

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r, that's just how Backbone is implemented. The route callback registered in the `routes` hash is called before any event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

This can be explained by taking a look at the [Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js):

```
this.trigger.apply(this, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
this.trigger('route', name, args);
```

Try listening for only the 'route' event:

```
@on 'route'
```